# List only workdays in given dynamic month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Haven't found anything on here about this yet...
My file is used by staff to track production each month. A cell on the sheet contains the first date of the month - i.e. `May 1, 2016`

I need to build a table that lists *only* workdays for the month indicated on the previous sheet (`May 1, 2016`). i've been able to use the **=WORKDAYS** function to create a list of workdays and use fill to complete the list of days in that month, but the problem is that it just continues on listing the dates in the subsequent month. I'm just using:

```
=WORKDAY(C2,1)  May 30
=WORKDAY(D2,1)  May 31
=WORKDAY(E2,1)  June 1
```

etc, to fill the dates. In my example I want Excel to return `""` rather than continue with the next month.

I'm assuming there's some sort of `IF` statement I can use, but I can't figure out how to avoid circular references if the check needs to check the very cell it is in...

Comment: You would check the previous cell to see if it is the last day of the month.  Just compare it using the [EOMONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, because not every month's last day is a workday (i.e. April, last workday is April 29, not April 30).

Comment: Check to see if month() pprevious row is the same as the MONTH() current row, if they are not "".  if they are equal enter your date for current row

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, here, but I don't understand the question. Can you not just stop filling at the end of the month? Or do you want to switch to the next cell on the previous worksheet and fill in those months, and the next, etc.?

Comment: Different months have different number of workdays (some 21, some 20, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `Sheet1` cell A1 is the date value `May 1, 2016`

On `Sheet2` cell A1 is a header, so actual dates will start in cell A2. In cell A2 is this formula to get the first workday of the month:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Sheet1!A1,2)<6,Sheet1!A1,WORKDAY(Sheet1!A1,1))
```

Then in cell A3 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,1))<>MONTH(A2),"",WORKDAY(A2,1)))
```

You will get results as shown. Note that I copied it down to cell A31 and it gives proper workday dates and stops at the end of the month:

[image: tigeravatar example for mattinwpg]

Comment: This is beautiful, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd suggest a slight updated to both formula:  `=IF(WEEKDAY(Sheet1!A1,2)<6,Sheet1!A1,WORKDAY(Sheet1!A1,1,BankHolidays))` and `=IF(A2="","",IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(A2,1))<>MONTH(A2),"",WORKDAY(A2,1,BankHolidays)))` where `BankHolidays` is a named range - this will remove 2nd and 30th May in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

How about this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(TEXT(D2,"yymm")<>TEXT(E2,"yymm"),"", WORKDAY(E2,1)),"")
```

It checks if month and year in cell D2 equal to month and year in cell E2. If this is not the case, it gives you a blank cell.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That throws circular reference errors - this is the problem i keep running in to.